# How to redirect to a page when session times out?

Tags: java, html, session, session-timeout

I am coming to a problem where I have a session timeout on my page and a html page that I created for when session timesout, it will go to that page. But, right now when session times out it goes to `index page` which I don't want to. Is there a way I can redirect the user to a timeout page? Thanks.

> here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Session Expired</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>


         <style type="text/css">


        html {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            line-height: 1.15;
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%
        }

        body {
            margin: 0
        }

        article,
        aside,
        footer,
        header,
        nav,
        section {
            display: block
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 2em;
            margin: .67em 0
        }

        figcaption,
        figure,
        main {
            display: block
        }

        figure {
            margin: 1em 40px
        }

        hr {
            box-sizing: content-box;
            height: 0;
            overflow: visible
        }

        pre {
            font-family: monospace, monospace;
            font-size: 1em
        }

        a {
            background-color: transparent;
            -webkit-text-decoration-skip: objects
        }

        a:active,
        a:hover {
            outline-width: 0
        }

        abbr[title] {
            border-bottom: none;
            text-decoration: underline;
            text-decoration: underline dotted
        }

        b,
        strong {
            font-weight: inherit
        }

        b,
        strong {
            font-weight: bolder
        }

        code,
        kbd,
        samp {
            font-family: monospace, monospace;
            font-size: 1em
        }

        dfn {
            font-style: italic
        }

        mark {
            background-color: #ff0;
            color: #000
        }

        small {
            font-size: 80%
        }

        sub,
        sup {
            font-size: 75%;
            line-height: 0;
            position: relative;
            vertical-align: baseline
        }

        sub {
            bottom: -.25em
        }

        sup {
            top: -.5em
        }

        audio,
        video {
            display: inline-block
        }

        audio:not([controls]) {
            display: none;
            height: 0
        }

        img {
            border-style: none
        }

        svg:not(:root) {
            overflow: hidden
        }

        button,
        input,
        optgroup,
        select,
        textarea {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 100%;
            line-height: 1.15;
            margin: 0
        }

        button,
        input {
            overflow: visible
        }

        button,
        select {
            text-transform: none
        }

        [type=reset],
        [type=submit],
        button,
        html [type=button] {
            -webkit-appearance: button
        }

        [type=button]::-moz-focus-inner,
        [type=reset]::-moz-focus-inner,
        [type=submit]::-moz-focus-inner,
        button::-moz-focus-inner {
            border-style: none;
            padding: 0
        }

        [type=button]:-moz-focusring,
        [type=reset]:-moz-focusring,
        [type=submit]:-moz-focusring,
        button:-moz-focusring {
            outline: 1px dotted ButtonText
        }

        fieldset {
            border: 1px solid silver;
            margin: 0 2px;
            padding: .35em .625em .75em
        }

        legend {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            color: inherit;
            display: table;
            max-width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            white-space: normal
        }

        progress {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: baseline
        }

        textarea {
            overflow: auto
        }

        [type=checkbox],
        [type=radio] {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 0
        }

        [type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
        [type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
            height: auto
        }

        [type=search] {
            -webkit-appearance: textfield;
            outline-offset: -2px
        }

        [type=search]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
        [type=search]::-webkit-search-decoration {
            -webkit-appearance: none
        }

        ::-webkit-file-upload-button {
            -webkit-appearance: button;
            font: inherit
        }

        details,
        menu {
            display: block
        }

        summary {
            display: list-item
        }

        canvas {
            display: inline-block
        }

        template {
            display: none
        }

        [hidden] {
            display: none
        }

        body,
        html {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #21232a
        }

        body {
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            text-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
            padding: 0;
            min-height: 100%;
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 75pt rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 75pt rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
            display: table;
            font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif
        }

        h1 {
            font-family: inherit;
            font-weight: 500;
            line-height: 1.1;
            color: inherit;
            font-size: 36px
        }

        h1 small {
            font-size: 68%;
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 1;
            color: #777
        }

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: inherit;
            border-bottom: dotted 1px #707070
        }

        .lead {
            color: silver;
            font-size: 21px;
            line-height: 1.4
        }

        .cover {
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
            padding: 0 20px
        }

        footer {
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            height: 40px;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            color: #a0a0a0;
            font-size: 14px
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="cover">
            <h1>Your session has expired  due to inactivity. </h1>
            <h1>  Please login again 
                  <a href="index.xhtml">here</a>. Thank you.</h1>


        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The html for your timeout isn't needed at all, because it will never be displayed according to your question. The problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: Check out [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-httpsessionlistener-example-active-sessions-counter/) then create same listener but you have to add  after session invalidate redirect the user to N page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a filter :

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
                    ServletException
    {


            String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();

            System.out.println("IP " + ipAddress + ", Time " + new Date().toString());

            boolean authorized = false;
            String username = null;
            String role = null;
            if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest)
            {
                    HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession(false);
                    if (session != null)
                    {
                            username = (String) session.getAttribute("username");
                            role = (String) session.getAttribute("role");
                            if (username != null && role != null)
                                    authorized = true;
                    }else{ 

                            ((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect("showlogin");
                    //or response.sendError(..) etc.
                    return ;
               }
            }
```

Comment: what does this do ?

Answer (score 0):

On Java, you have  a httpSessionListener interface.
When you implement this interface, you have to implement 2 methods :

**sessionCreated(httpSessionEvent e)**
**sessionDestroyed(httpSessionEvent e)**

SessionDestroyed is activated when a session dies.so you Can put your code into this method.

Édit:

```
Class Listen implements httpSessionListener {
Public void SessionDestroyed (httpSessionEvent e){
 //Redirection code
}
}
```

//Web.xml:

```
<Listener>
<Listener-class>path of class</listener-class>
</Listener>
```

The XML listener tag must be outside th servlet tag.

Comment: so I have a method: `public void destroy()` should I put the page `timeout` inside that method?

Comment: Normaly, you use httpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(int sec) to set the duration of one session.then thé lister is called automaticly when thé session is over. You just have to put your redirection code into thé listener

Comment: The listener must implements httpSessionListener

Comment: Can you please show me some code prior to my code above?

Comment: because my session-timeout is in my `web.xml`

Comment: that where the server times up

Comment: I édited my answer, just create a listener class ans add à reference to it in the web.xml .

Answer (score 0):

The user-friendly solution would be to make a javascript-timeout the same duration as your sessiontimeout und bring a popup 60 seconds before the ending in front to warn the user about the issue...

Comment: I have created a js timeout but when the server session-timeout hits that minute it automatically logs the user out and takes to `index` page

Comment: now, when session times out its show my 500 custom error page.

Comment: you should rethink your Filter-Class. Is it really smart to alway send all not logged in user to the same page? So you can have only one page for not registered user (your index.jsp). No room for other pages like your session-timeout-page...

Comment: my session-timeout expires in my `web.xml` that is why

Comment: Yes i know we had the same problem. You have to redesign your filter class. So only one page for not registered people (like the ones without session) is possible.

Comment: ByTheWay: i would make the js part other way:

Comment: what is the other way of JS?

Comment: show simply a popup in sessionTimoutInMilis-90000 and warn the user with down-counting time in the popup.
This is the way we make this.
After the real timeout you can redirect (if you first ReEdited your Filter-Class)

Comment: The less risk change would be: 
check before your "sendRedirect" if the request, requests your session-timeout-page.
Not very nice but without knowing your full application i can make no other suggestions...

Comment: ""now, when session times out its show my 500 custom error page."" If thats the case you should post the stackTrace from your error-page....